# Limiting number of calls using Yahoo YQL in C#

Tags: c#, api, limit, yql, yahoo-finance

I'm a bit new to C# and i'm running into a problem with YQL limiting the number of calls to 10,000 an hour.  I keep getting my temp ban everytime I try to run my app.  I read that Yahoo has a limit of 10,000 calls per hour but i'm a little confused about what exactly constitutes a "call."  The code I"m using to get the XML from YQL is below:

```
    public static string getXml(string sSymbol)
    {

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=" + sSymbol);

        string xmlraw = doc.ToString();
        string xml = xmlraw.Replace("'", "");


        return xml;

    }
```

Where sSymbol is a value that is returned from my SQL DB.  I have roughly 2,000 stocks in my Database.  I have also read that some people are saying 1,000 calls per hour so I have has misunderstood what I was reading.

The question I guess is two-fold:  What constitutes a calls?

How can I avoid this rate limit if I want to download each of the 2,000 quotes per hour?  Is it as simple as asking yahoo for 200 quotes per Load and calling the Load 10 times?

Answer (score 0):

For this case a call is a request. If you want to make single stock requests you need 2000 calls. Fortunately you can make one call requesting more than one stock as with Yahoo.

http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=MSFT&stock=IBM